# Most efficient way to search and manipulate Data: Array, classobject, collection?

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is to read and manipulate a list of data from different customers in an efficient way.

I have data looking like this. With 40+ columns and 500+ rows.
[image: DataTable]

I want to make this data useable (searchable and manipulateable) in my userforms and functions.
For example, i want to filter this data to all customers from one city.
Or Show only male customers in a Listbox.
Or add a new address to a specific customer.

The different approaches i have used are as follows:

- Storing every row in an array on startup
- Creating a Class clsCustomer and creating an object for every row on startup
- Reading from the table by accessing specific ranges

I have not yet used collections at all.

Things i noticed:

- reading and writing to ranges is very slow
- using arrays feels odd to write, since the references are always numbers
- creating a class feels like i am only recreating an array, unless i use methods/functions with it

What would be the most resource efficient way to write this in vba?

- in terms of speed
- in terms of readability of the code

Comment: The "data" you try showing is not understandable, I am afraid. A picture, in such a case, should be better I think. Theoretically, using arrays should produce the fastest code (processing them only in memory and drop the processing result at once, at the end. But not understanding what you effectively want accomplishing is difficult to make a clearer suggestion... Basically, you should try placing **the whole range in an array** and process it when necessary. "searchable and manipulateable" is abstract. Can you better explain what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry, i tried using the Table Markdown mentioned in the editor and the preview showed it fine. I added a screenshot of it to be more clear.

Comment: OK. What do you want accomplishing in terms of "searchable and manipulateable" abstract 'need'?

Comment: I added this to my question. What im trying to do is get a good base for further use of the data in vba. So i want to make it easy to search and filter data and manipulate datasets.

Comment: You do not show enough fields in order to receive more concrete suggestions, I am afraid. For each mentioned goal, there are different optimal ways to accomplish. For instance, you can rapidly obtain (from the whole array) **everything split per cities, if there is this information in the range**, using a `Dictionary`... Do you want extracting the city from the address?

Comment: Unfortuantely i do not have all the requirements, since this is a very early state. Rather than a specific case i would like to start with a solid base that is versatile and open for future requests, without having to change everything, and without cluttering up to much resources.

Comment: interacting with data in the sheet (i.e. ranges) is resource intense.  However past that you can do a lot in arrays in very little time and 500 ish rows with 40 ish columns is not going to cause any issues.  to @FaneDuru's point though if you dont have city as a field you will have to search address for those cities, also how do you plan to populate the city drop down in the first place.  these are probably things you need to consider.  that being said vba deals with arrays quickly, even if the coding can get repetitive!

Comment: If you try creating an 'approach', without knowing what exactly is to be done is wrong, in my opinion. Placing a large range in an array takes milliseconds... You can place there what is/looks to be useful for a specific task. You do not show enough elements to let me post a piece of code, as an example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try to understand the next fast way of data processing. Since your question do not clarify too much about the other columns content, it assumes that in the fourth column the cities exist:

```
Sub ArrayDictionaryApproach()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrItem, i As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here any sheet you need
   lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
   arr = sh.Range("A2:E" & lastR).value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 4)) Then
            dict.Add arr(i, 4), arr(i, 2)
        Else
            dict(arr(i, 4)) = dict(arr(i, 4)) & "|" & arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print dict.Keys()(0), dict.Items()(0)
    arrItem = Split(dict.Items()(0), "|")
    Debug.Print UBound(arrItem), arrItem(0)
End Sub
```

It will return all customer names from a specific city, split by "|". Using `Split` function you can place them in an array and deal with any needed way of processing...

Comment: I found another question with exactly what i was trying to say: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740862/code-optimisation-arrays-vs-collections Unfortunately i was not good enough to express it in english.

Comment: @MZiegaus I cannot stop myself asking what you understood from the linked thread... It treats a different aspect. How will you use a collection with 40 columns? Then, the code from the initial question is primitive... `ReDim Preserve` with a unit at any iteration is very bad from memory handling point of view. you should estimate/calculate a dimension bigger than the larger expected range, then `Redim Preserve` only once, at the end, according to a variable counting that dimension elements. Besides that, VBA offer the possibility to load and drop the processing result at once, in milliseconds.

Comment: The linked thread handles the efficiency in terms of memory/speed of the methods mentioned in my question. It compares the methods in an objective way, wich i tried to understand. The problem was me articulating it in an odd way. Thats also why i didnt find the thread before.

Comment: @MZiegaus The arrays world is complex... What I tried emphasizing was the fact that dealing with **1D** arrays, as the thread treats is much different than dealing with 2D arrays, as mostly is necessary when processing Excel ranges. You cannot even compare their efficiency in the way done there. Of course, if do are not too familiar with such objects, it is not bad to start understanding them. But "manipulating" data elements in a 2D array is something beyond the general rules applied in 1D arrays, collections or ArrayLists... But they offer some peculiarities, advantages good to be understood