# Alternate solution for CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList") error -2146232576 (80131700)

Tags: vba

My VBA:

```vb
Dim numericColumnNames As Object
Set numericColumnNames = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
```

The second line triggers:

> Run-time error '-2146232576 (80131700)':
> Automation error.

I found [this](https://pythonandvba.com/blog/fix-run-time-error-2146232576-80131700/). Is this the only solution? Could I use any different object instead? What could be done to avoid installing additional packages? To *"install additional packages"* is really frustrating for the end users.

Comment: Your question is strange... To use a different object for **doing what**? It may be different ways to do the same thing, but firstly you must show a piece of code using `ArrayList` to receive an equivalent solution...

Comment: Depending on your needs. Regular VBA-Arrays, Collection, Dictionaries...

Comment: I read here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740862/code-optimisation-arrays-vs-collections#answer-45741887)) that `Collection` is much faster than `ArrayList` so what is the point in even using the `ArrayList`. What does it have that `Collection` doesn't?

Comment: Scripting.Dictionaries should already e installed on your computer, its just a case of adding the appropriate reference in VBA.  If you are looking to use features of the ArrayList because your needs are  not met by the built in VBA collection then its a relatively simple exercise to extend and improve the collection object by wrapping it in another class.

Comment: The problem is that end user doens't know how to do that and it ruins the experience for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just add any .NET object to a VBA project. You can only use COM visible objects in VBA. You could write a COM wrapper around any .NET methods you want to use but then you need to register that DLL on each system where your VBA code will be used. It's a lot of work, and in your case for nothing.

Even if you could, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-6.0) tells you not to use this object at all:

> Important
>
> We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new
> development. Instead, we recommend that you use the generic List
> class. The ArrayList class is designed to hold heterogeneous
> collections of objects.

So the answer is to use a VBA `Collection` object.

```
Dim numericColumnNames As New Collection
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was suspecting that I ought to use the `Collection` as well after I read some literature yesterday. Thank you very much for the official reference where they say we shouldn't use `ArrayLists`. This is all I needed, because if officials say it, then that is it...